# SQL Joining on Different cell values

Tags: sql

I'm trying to join two tables based on the first two digits of UK Postcodes. The problem I have is that not all postcodes in my table start with two letters. For example:

```
Table 1 
Birmingham B
Bath    BA


Table 2
B5 5NR
BA1 2BX
```

If I was to join using LEFT(Postcode,2) I would be excluding Birmingham. If I was to join using LEFT(Postcode,1) I would be excluding Bath. Is there a way to just take the first text part of a postcode?

Many Thanks

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following query, assuming that the second table contains a number after the postcode to which we need to cut off to extract the postcode.

```
SELECT Name,A.Code,B.Code,B.Val 
FROM table1 A
JOIN table2 B ON A.Code =LEFT(B.Code,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',B.Code)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the postcode in table 1 is the shorter on, have you tried an substring with length of the postcode in table 1.

Something like SubString(table1.postcode, 0, length(table1.postcode))

This should work as the join condition. Try it please.

Comment: Thanks for your help Kn0rK3, I tried this but all I get back is 'LENGTH' is not a recognized built-in function name?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. T-SQL it is LEN not LENGTH

Answer (score 0):

This will eliminate the last character of a string in SQL Server:

```
LEFT(Postcode,LEN(Postcode)-1)
```